# haskell own datatypes - using signs or numbers in the datatype definition

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I have a question according to the definition of datatypes:
Is it possible to use signs or numbers in the definition?
For instance if I want to create a datatype for the lower and equal sign the following code works of course

```
data Signs = Lo | Eq
```

The constructor Lo stands for "<" and the constructor Eq is "=".

But I can't use the "real" signs. For instance the following codes won't work

```
data Signs = Lo "<" | Eq "=" 
type Signs = "<" | "="
type MyInt = '1' | '2'
data MyInt = One '1' | Two '2'
```

So I would like to know if there is a possibility to use "real" signs and numbers within the definition. And if there is one it would be nice if you could tell me how it works. ;)

Comment: Do you want them just for convenience purposes?

Comment: @dbaupp: not just for convenience but I'm interested to know it. To me it is a little bit strange that a build-in datatype like for instance "Int" is hard to reimplement. Or how would you try to implement a datatype "data MyInt = ..." that is equivalent to "Int"?

Answer (score 2):

Operator identifiers prefixed with `:` can be used in data constructors.

```
data Signs = (:<) | (:=)
```

if they are nullary then AFAIK you have to keep the parens:

```
[(:<), (:=)]
```

You can use numbers but the first character must be an uppercase letter.

```
data MyInt = N1 | N2
```

See http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html

Comment: All this time I had assumed an infix data constructor had to take exactly two arguments... and I was wrong.

Comment: @jimmyt Don't forget to mark answers as correct! (green checkmark)